# Accessing object properties in an array

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to check my database for login information and receive it back inside the application but I am having the issue that I cannot parse the JSON information. I have parsed it into an array and when I run the following code the console returns:

[image]

I am wondering how do I take this a step further and read the number for "loggedin" and get the "username" also. I have tried replacing myArr with myArr[0].loggedin or even with myArr[0] but then I get a return of undefined.

Anyone any suggestions?

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', function() {
        var usernameTest = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var passwordTest = document.getElementById('username').value;
            //alert("username is: " + usernameTest);
            //console.log("password is: " + passwordTest);
            //alert("test");
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                alert(this.responseText);
                var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(myArr);

            }
        };

        request.open('GET', 'http://localhost/api/login.php?username='+usernameTest+'&password='+passwordTest);
        request.send();

        });
    });
```

Comment: myArr.UAPLogin[0].UAPLogin[0].loggedin  .....

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me after GaetanoM's comment is:

```
myArr.UAPlugin[0].loggedin or myArr.UAPlugin[0].username
```